# If $m(A)=0$ and $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ has bounded derivative then $m(f(A))=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $A\subset [0,1]$. Show that if $m(A)=0$ and $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ has bounded derivative then $m(f(A))=0$.

($m$ denotes Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$)

---

If $m(A)=0$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is open set $G\subset [0,1]$ such that $A\subset G$ and $m(G)<\epsilon /B$. Since $G$ is open it is the union of countably many disjoint open intervals $\{G_i\}_{i=1,2,\ldots}$ so we have 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} m(G_i)<\epsilon / B \mbox{.}$$

Let $M>0$ be such that $f'(x)<B$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

For every $G_i$ and any two points $x,y$ in $G_i$ from MVT we know that

$$|f(x)-f(y)|<B |x-y| \mbox{.}$$

Also since $G_1,G_2,\ldots$ are disjoint we know that $f(A)\subset f(G)=\bigcup_i f(G_i)$.

Finally

$$m(f(A))\le m(f(G))\le\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}m(f(G_i))<\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}Bm(G_i)<B \epsilon / B=\epsilon$$

(Above I have also used the fact that continuous function maps connected subsets to connected subsets)

My question is if the above reasoning is correct.
$$$$

Comment: It looks correct to me.  I would define $B$ at the start, before defining $G$.  I would also change $M$ to $B$.

Comment: I'm not sure about $m(f(G))=\sum m(f(G_i))$? What if the $f(G_i)$ are not disjoint? I think your proof still works by changing it to $\leq$ though :)

Comment: @charlestoncrabb you're right! I fixed it.